# How to catch with javascript an html element (from DOM) by it's 'this' returning?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to get an HTML element with `querySelector` but it returns `null`. 
How can I get it?

`btn` is 'this' of a button:

```
<button class="Medium" onclick="restartGame(this, 1)">Medium</button>
```

The function I was trying is:

```
function setCurrLevel(btn) {
    var elCurrBtn = document.querySelector(`${btn.class}`);

    if (elCurrBtn.innerText === 'Easy') {
        gCurrLevel = 0; 
    } else if (elCurrBtn.innerText === 'Medium') {
        gCurrLevel = 1; 
    } else if (elCurrBtn.innerText === 'Hard') {
        gCurrLevel = 2; 
    } 

    return gCurrLevel;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML element you're trying to select ?

Comment: Your HTML's `onClick` is using `restartGame`, but your quoted function is `setCurrLevel`...?

Answer (score 1):

If `btn` already refers to the button, you don't need `querySelector` at all. Just use `btn`:

```js
var gCurrLevel;
function setCurrLevel(btn) {
  if (btn.innerText === 'Easy') {
    gCurrLevel = 0;
  } else if (btn.innerText === 'Medium') {
    gCurrLevel = 1;
  } else if (btn.innerText === 'Hard') {
    gCurrLevel = 2;
  }

  console.log("gCurrLevel = " + gCurrLevel);
  // return gCurrLevel; // Don't do this in an event handler
}
```

```html
<button class="Medium" onclick="setCurrLevel(this)">Medium</button>
```

There I've replaced `resetGame(this, 1)` with `setCurrLevel(this)` so they match up, but adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If your button element is passed to setCurrLevel, you don't need to select it anymore

```
  function setCurrLevel(btn) {
    var gCurrLevel = 0;
    if (btn.innerText === 'Easy') {
        gCurrLevel = 0; 
    } else if (btn.innerText === 'Medium') {
        gCurrLevel = 1; 
    } else if (btn.innerText === 'Hard') {
        gCurrLevel = 2; 
    } 

    return gCurrLevel;
 }
```